# How can I set reference zoom level in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, display, resolution, zoom

I want to make 100% zoom level the actual paper size display on my screen in Microsoft Word.

For example, I want the current, unmodified 125% zoom (which equals to the real paper size) to be 100% in Word, so I can select 100% zoom and get the actual page size on the display, where I previously had to choose 125% to get the correct screen size.

Can this be done in the current version of Microsoft Word, and if so, how?